# How to properly use Duplex streams in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

I need to write a script that would fetch files from [Azure blob storage](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/#toc6__anchor) and push them into github repository via [github's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) .

[azure-storage package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage) provides the method `blobService.getBlobToStream` which expects its 3rd argument to be a stream, `fs.createWriteStream('output.txt')` is given as an example

however to upload to github one needs to provide base64-encoded content of the file. I use [base64-stream package](https://github.com/mazira/base64-stream)

I've checked that each step works on its own, i.e. I download the file from azure first, then save it on disk, then read from disk and encode it, then upload to github

```
// download first
blobService.getBlobToStream('...', '...', fs.createWriteStream('out'), ...
    var b64file = '';
    fs.createReadStream('out')
      .pipe(require('base64-stream').encode())
      .on('data', function (chunk) {
          b64file += chunk;
      })
      .on('end', function () {
          // upload to github
      });
```

Can I do this without the intermittent step of saving the file on disk? A stream which I can pass to `blobService.getBlobToStream` as writable, but also `.pipe()` as readable?

From [node'js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex) it seems that `require('stream').Duplex` is what I'm looking for, but I can't make it work and examples I've found are not very enlightening either. If I just use it like

```
var Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;
var wr_stream = new Duplex;
var b64file = '';
    wr_stream.createReadStream('out')
      .pipe(require('base64-stream').encode())
      .on('data', function (chunk) {
          b64file += chunk;
      })
      .on('end', function () {
          // upload to github
      });
 // now I can download
 blobService.getBlobToStream('...', '...', wr_stream, ...
```

I get exception

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: not implemented
    at Duplex.Readable._read (_stream_readable.js:449:22)
    at Duplex.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:328:10)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:718:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:351:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:962:3
```

Comment: You have to extend a duplex stream an use your own implementation of `_read` and `_write`.

Comment: @ryan0319 could you provide a more detailed example?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_duplex_stream

Answer (score 0):

Since you have streams all around you don't need to create any custom stream. Just pipe them:

```
const { Base64Encode } = require('base64-stream')
const { WriteStream } = require('fs')
const blobService = azure.createBlobService()

const writer = new WriteStream('output.txt')
const encoder = new Base64Encode()

encoder.pipe(writer)

blobService('...', '...', encoder)
```